# Java version error while running SpringBoot Application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have just started with springboot and was making this basic code which is given by SpringIntializer.
But after running java -jar quickstart2-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar I am getting the following error,
" Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/loader/launch/JarLauncher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0 ".

as far as I understood the error it is related to some version issues.
below is the application code

```
package com.revati.quickstart2;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Quickstart2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Quickstart2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I check the java -version in terminal it gives following :

openjdk version "11.0.16.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-40648 (build 11.0.16.1+1-LTS)

Using some suggestion from the net, I have installed the latest java version (21), updated the JAVA_HOME variable and also checked the project structure so that the module and SDKs have java 21 itself.

Here is the poml screenshot

[image][image]

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\OpenJDK\jdk-21.0.1

Please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: You're running your application with Java 11, but Spring Boot 3 requires at least Java 17. So, fix your PATH environment variable so it correctly point to your Java 21 installation. Also, for future reference **do not post images of code**. In this case you say you changed JAVA_HOME, and that probably means that you need to fix your PATH.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have fixed the PATH as well to Java 21 bin. I don't know why IntelliJ shows Java 11. Checked the project structure as well

Comment: If you're running from within IntelliJ, then it uses the JDK you have configured in your project. That means you configured IntelliJ to use Java 11, change it to point to Java 21 (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S, Project, SDK).